# How to listen to TabBar index changes in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using a custom `TabController` with the `TabBar` in flutter.

I want to listen when the `tab index` changes and do some operation on it. (in my case it is to change the appbar. If it is tab 0 i want to show a save button, otherwise not show it)

My code so far is:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditPostPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditPostPageState createState() => _EditPostPageState();
}

class _EditPostPageState extends State<EditPostPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );

    // TODO how to listen to index changes here ?
    // I want to listen and Stream them with a streamcontroller which will listen on line 54
    // and render or not the save button

    //_tabController.listen
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _tabBar = TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      indicatorColor: AppColors.Primary,
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: 'tab 1',),
        Tab(text: 'tab 2',),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Text('Edit Post'),
              if (_tabController.index == 0)
                SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery
                        .of(context)
                        .size
                        .width * 0.2,
                    child: RoundedButton(
                      text: t.save_btn,
                      color: AppColors.Secondary,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // TODO
                      },
                    ))
            ],
          ),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: _tabBar.preferredSize,
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: _tabBar,
            ),
          )),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Text('tab 1 content'),
          Text('tab 2 content'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can read the todo comment in the code to see what I am lacking to finish this.

There exists one `TabController.addListener` method but the callback can be a void function and does not receive the `int index` so I am not sure if that is reliable and the correct way. I checked the source code of `TabController` and the listeners are notified also while index change starts and seems suspicious.

Other solutions that achieve the same goal and might be even better are welcome as well. Thanks

Comment: but that will be triggered also for "no reason" while the index starts to change. I want to do my expensive update calculations only when being 100% sure that the index changed. I can come up with a hacky workaround though store oldIndex in state and check if index changed on listener only then update my state and do some operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and looked the entire source code of TabController and did not find a specific way to listen `only to indexChange`.

The only solution I came up with that also good performance and triggers `only 1 time when the index changes` and does not trigger my function during the index change is the one below:

```
  int _previousTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(_listenToTabChanges);
  }

  void _listenToTabChanges() {
      if (_previousTabIndex != _tabController.index) {
         _previousTabIndex = _tabController.index;
         // do something now. Here we are 100% sure that the index changed and not started to change or something else and trigger unecesary multiple-operations
      }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_listenToTabChanges);
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```